# Why Qt5 QEvent::FocusIn does not work with QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget

I changed the anchestor type of my object from `QMainWindow` to `QWidget`. This stopped eventFilter() to work. As shown below, I replaced `QEvent::FocusIn` with `QEvent::Enter`, and this works with both `QMainWindow` and `QWidget`. As I guess from the debugger, `event->type()` returns some unrecognized code for `QWidget`. Is it a kind of bug or I misinterpret something?

```
bool CoreWidget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if ((obj == this) &&  
//      (event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn) )
        (event->type() == QEvent::Enter) )
      {
        //!! MyAction
          return true;
      }
    else
    {
        // pass the event on to the parent class
      return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: QEvent::FocusIn event is get only widgets, which can have gains keyboard focus. Did you try it for edit box?

Comment: An event filter for `this` makes very little sense. That's just `QObject::event`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not consider that FocusIn is related to to some visible object, which can be selected.

Comment: @peppe It has sense: another window changes its content if mouse moves above this widget.

Comment: I'm saying that in order to get the events delivered to "this" you don't install an event filter on "this", you override "event()".

Comment: @peppe  The object was originally QMainWindow, but since its functionality was reduced to minimum during development, I attempted to replace it with QWidget.